# Simple Palindrome check in Python?

Tags: python, string, reverse, slice, palindrome

I am doing a palindrome check program for school, but there is a twist.

Now I already know that I could use a reverse function or something like:

```
[-1::-1]
```

However, the program specifically calls for no string slicing or use of the .reverse() function. So, my question is how would I go about doing this if I cannot use these two simple methods?

Comment: You might have to use typical character comparison method with loops then.

Comment: Does `a[1:-1]` count as a slice? What about `a[0]`?

Comment: I don't think you would use `[-1::-1]`, just `[::-1]` works and is more readable.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask it as a new question rather than editing an existing one.

Answer (score 5):

It's clear that this is for academic purposes only because using reversed function this code would be trivial.

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    for i,char in enumerate(string):
        if char != string[-i-1]:
            return False
    return True

>>> is_palindrome('hello')
False    
>>> is_palindrome('helloolleh')
True
>>> is_palindrome('')
True
>>> is_palindrome(' ')
True
>>> is_palindrome('a')
True
```

Comment: a little more overhead, but `p = lambda s: sum([s[i] != s[-i-1] for i in range(len(s)/2)]) == 0`

Answer (score 4):

Canonical solution would be:

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    result = True
    str_len = len(string)
    for i in range(0, int(str_len/2)): # you need to check only half of the string
        if string[i] != string[str_len-i-1]:
            result = False
            break
    return result # single return statement is considered a good practice
```

Comment: Good solution, but I have to dispute the assertion that a single return statement is considered good practice in Python. In fact I'll say the `break` is unnecessary and two return statements make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need any `reverse` function at all to check if something is a palindrome. Consider:

- an empty string is a palindrome
- a string of length 1 is a palindrome
- every other string is a palindrome if its first and last characters are equal and the "middle" part (without the first and the last chars) is a palindrome, recursively.

Try to implement this in python - it's easy! (Hint: the last char is `str[-1]` and the middle is `str[1:-1]`).